# Why I get HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, generator, metamodel

I have to deal with a view declared as following (Oracle 11g):

```sql
  create view V_SOME_VIEW as
  select X, Y
  from SOME_TABLE
```

and an entity for it:

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@Table("V_SOME_VIEW")
@NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name = "VSomeView.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM VSomeView v")})
public class VSomeView implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Lob
   @Column(name = "X")
   private Object x;

   @Lob
   @Column(name = "Y")
   private Object y;

   ...    
}
```

After generating a static metamodel using [Gradle Metamodel Plugin](https://github.com/Scalified/gradle-metamodel-plugin) I have the following metamodel **without attribute y**:

```java
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(VSomeView.class)
public abstract class VSomeView_ {

   public static volatile SingularAttribute<VSomeView, Object> x;

   public static final String X = "x";
}
```

At application start I have errors like this:

> ERROR o.h.ejb.metamodel.MetadataContext: HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field: ...VSomeView_#y

If I change column type from `java.lang.Object` to `java.lang.String` the field **y** is generated correctly. Can someone explain me, what's the reason for this, please?

Comment: See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic). By default hibernate use java.lang.String for `CLOB` JDBC type. Otherwise, you should use [custom hibernate type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type).

Comment: @SternK, thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I still have no understanding **why** does incorrect type cause metamodel property missing. I've tried to google for it, but had no result. Couldn't you, please, point to a doc section or give a brief explanation of that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain, why you want to declare `x, y` fields as  `java.lang.Object`? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. It's legacy code and I just tried to figure out, why some of metamodel's attributes are missing. In fact, there are few cases where fields are actually BLOBs. Most of them are just VARCHARs. Taking in account your first comment, I think it would be better just to fix types in Java code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From JPA specification

> **6.2.1.1 Canonical Metamodel**
>
> For every persistent non-collection-valued attribute `y` declared by class `X`, where the type of `y` is `Y`, the metamodel class must contain a declaration as follows:
>
> `public static volatile SingularAttribute<X, Y> y;`

So, from this point of view, your expectation to see `y` property in the metamodel class looks substantiated.

But diving into the Hibernate implementation of the annotation processor
[JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/tooling/metamodel-generator/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.java), we can find out that a **non-collection-valued attribute** will be present at the metamodel class if the method **isBasicAttribute** of the class [MetaAttributeGenerationVisitor](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/tooling/metamodel-generator/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/annotation/MetaAttributeGenerationVisitor.java) returns **true**.

It is possible in the following cases:

1. The persistent attribute is annotated by one of the following annotations:
   [@Basic](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html), [@OneToOne](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html), [@ManyToOne](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html), [@EmbeddedId](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html), [@Id](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Id.html).
2. The persistent attribute is annotated with the annotation [@Type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-type) what means it is a hibernate custom type.
3. The persistent attribute is [an enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).
4. The persistent attribute is [a primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)
5. The persistent attribute is [a hibernate basic type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic)
6. The persistent attribute is a class that implements [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.
7. The persistent attribute is a class annotated with the [@Embeddable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) annotation.

Your first persistent attribute meet the n.1 condition due to the `@Id` annotation, but the second one does not meet n.1-7 conditions that is why it is absent in the generated metamodel.

See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html).

Comment: Wow! I appreciate your detailed answer a lot! Now it's all clear to me! Hooray!